# Download a file in Angular Environment

Tags: angularjs, download

I need to download a file from the server. The file is stored in the database. I have a cs controller that serves a file back to UI. The server GET call looks like this:

```
http://server/api/controllername/fileid/data
```

It does work when I run that link in the Browser - the file comes down and goes into the download area (Chrome). But when I send the same command from my Angualar code  I dont see any file. The console reports that my request was successful (code 200), but I just dont see anything. Please let me know what code fragments to post to make it easier to help.

Thanks

Comment: Don't request it with http, instead request it as if you were leaving the page to visit that url, either in the current tab or a new tab, or even an iframe.

Comment: If you send an AJAX request, you're basically telling the browser: i want to handle the response of that request the way I want, with JavaScript code. Why do you send an AJAX request rather than simply letting the user click on a regular link?

Comment: What kind of data is it? JSON, XML or is it a page fragment (HTML)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a link to the resource, and don't handle it with ajax.

If you make the link open in a new tab, the tab will automatically close after it realises it was just opened to download a file in most modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = "http://server/api/controllername/fileid/data";
a.click();
```

You can compose the address concatenating variables and text.

Comment: Why not simply use `window.location = 'http://server/api/controllername/fileid/data'`?

Comment: I use that code in a web page that creates a XML file and let you save it locally. If I use your suggestion my browser (chrome) shows the XML file, when I use the one I described above it will automatically download the file. I don't know if that may affect other file or mime types.

Answer (score 1):

The file probably downloads correctly as a byte[] to the calling it but that would be useless to the user - as was my problem.

In my case I needed to download a file with a complex set of parameters. This example JavaScript uses a post request and creates a form (and posts it) with any JavaScript  object that you give it. This code may help if you simplified it:

```js
private open(verb, url, data, target)
    {
        var form = document.createElement("form");
        form.action = url;
        form.method = verb;
        form.target = target || "_self";
        if (data) {
            this.createFormParameters(form, "", data);
        }

        form.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();
    }


    private createFormParameters(form, key, value) {
        // recursive algorithm to add parameters (including objects and arrays of objects) to a custom form

        if (typeof value === "object") {
            for (var item in value) {

                if (Array.isArray(value[item])) {
                    for (var arrayItem in value[item]) {
                        this.createFormParameters(form, (item + "[" + arrayItem + "]."), value[item][arrayItem]);
                    }
                    continue;
                }

                var input = document.createElement("textarea");
                input.name = key + item;
                input.value = value[item];
                form.appendChild(input);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var input = document.createElement("textarea");
            input.name = key;
            input.value = value;
            form.appendChild(input);
        }
    }
```